# Prove that $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}, P(X > a, Y > b) = 1 - F_X(a) - F_Y(b) + F_{X, Y}(a, b)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is to prove that $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $P(X > a, Y > b) = 1 - F_X(a) - F_Y(b) + F_{X, Y}(a, b)$. Here is my attempt at it :

$1 = P(X \in \mathbb{R}, Y \in \mathbb{R}), F_X(a) = \lim\limits_{b \nearrow \infty} P(X \leq a, Y \leq b), F_Y(b) = \lim\limits_{a \nearrow \infty} P(X \leq a, Y \leq b), F_{X, Y}(a, b) = P(X \leq a, Y \leq b)$. Now I am stuck on how to prove the rest of the problem. I intuitively understand how the proof works and know how the proof works in practice but I am unable to complete my proof by writing it rigorously. Can someone help me here?

Comment: $$I(X > a, Y > b) = I(X > a)I(Y > b) = (1 - I(X \leq a))(1 - I(Y \leq b)).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
     \mathbb{P}(X > a, Y > b) = 1 - \mathbb{P}((X \le a) \cup (Y \le b))
$$
But,
$$
    \begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}((X \le a) \cup (Y \le b)) &= \mathbb{P}(X \le a) + \mathbb{P}(Y \le b) - \mathbb{P}(X \le a, Y \le b)\\ &= F_X(a) + F_Y(b) - F_{X, Y}(a, b)
    \end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!